# creature pupils, iris color, and eye shape. What would they look like?

Tags: biology, creature-design, mythical-creatures

There are several species I've thought up for fun. Pure entertainment.

One species is 4-5 feet tall, and lives in very dark caves where the only light source is the luminescence of fauna, the glow of crystals, or bits of sunlight (if they live close to the surface). They are predators who hunt and live in groups of 3-4.
In this world there are animals that live in the caves, and the species would primarily subsist off of them. The prey is diverse in size but the species would target the larger varieties.
They would be ambush predators, but they are not very fast. They make up for this in pure strength and cutting off any exit. They crush the prey with their thick, large claws.
Occasionally this species may go to the surface, but they cannot see very well since it's too bright.

Another species is semi-aquatic and about 6-7 feet tall. They live in mangroves and swamps but they cannot breathe water. They can hold their breath for up to an hour and they cruise the water like alligators, hunting from the water (or sometimes on land) and ambushing alligators, birds, and animals like raccoons and bobcats. A smaller part of their diet is fish and crabs but they mainly subsist off of alligators.
They hunt smaller animals by crushing or drowning them under the water, and they hunt alligators by pinning them with spears and clawing them with their hooked, webbed talons. The species can see in the dark as well as humans can (which is not much). They have a secondary eyelid for protecting them from the water.

Edit: I realize I was unspecific when I was describing what I was looking for. I'm wondering what kind of pupil these species would logically have, based off how they hunt, their basic environment, and their height. I'm also wondering what would the eye shape or position it would logically be on the head, and what size or color iris/sclera would make sense for them.

Comment: The question could/should be worded differently to avoid the smell of multiple questions.  Something along the line of how to determine eye properties specifically pupil shape, iris color, eye shape. Some creatures I want to apply this to are....

Comment: The first group/creature to be plausible would need a large supply of food arriving from the surface on a continual basis. They are HUGE for underground. Where is their prey getting food from.

Comment: Their prey is getting food from the large amounts of fauna and smaller prey in the underground (because this is a fantasy world). It is more lively than real life cave systems.

Answer (score 1):

For the first species I would not have any traditional movable eyeballs but rather some bee or insect-styled multiple-cell receptor patch where the eye should be. The more the better. Your creature seems a lot like a cave spider. Any colour will do, but contrasting colours like yellow/red, or even white would be pretty cool, because (I'm assuming) these creatures have dark colours.

For the second species, a reptile's slit eyes would be cool, with a diagonal shape. The colour really depends on the colour of the animal body - if it's a dark/black-purple coloured body I'd suggest red/gold pupils against a white/black eyeball.